I have to insert a transaction and apply the tran amount to multiple columns in a waterfall method
I have a table with multiple transactions.
For each transaction amount. I have to apply the amount to int, esc and principle in a waterfall method.
For the next record, the balances from the previous record should be the base to apply the next tran
I tried but no luck.
Could you please assist
